# Что-то не импортируются таблицы css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Хочу объединить в style.css все другие таблицы (header,nav и тд) и подключать только его к html, однако есть какая-то ошибка которую я не вижу, а также имеется ошибка в консоли браузера.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Путь к файлам
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (style.css)

```
@import url(styles\parts\_container.css);
```

(_container.css)

```
.container {
    margin: 60px auto;
    width: 1100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 280px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 100px 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: А так `@import url("styles\parts\_container.css");`? Или так `@import "styles\parts\_container.css";`? https://doka.guide/css/import/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мы импортируем в style.css и нужный файл находится в parts, то так
@import url(./parts/_container.css);